# Bash code for image scraper not working

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Desc: Images downloader
#Filename: img_downloader.sh
if [ $# -ne 3 ];
then
echo "Usage: $0 URL -d DIRECTORY"
exit -1
fi
for i in {1..4}
do
case $1 in
-d) shift; directory=$1; shift ;;
*) url=${url:-$1}; shift;;
esac
done
mkdir -p $directory;
baseurl=$(echo $url | egrep -o "https?://[a-z.]+")
echo Downloading $url
curl -s $url | egrep -o "<img src=[^>]*>" |
sed 's/<img src=\"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g' > /tmp/$$.list
sed -i "s|^/|$baseurl/|" /tmp/$$.list
cd $directory;
while read filename;
do
echo Downloading $filename
curl -s -O "$filename" --silent
done < /tmp/$$.list
```

And it’s run as is given as:

```
gavish@gavish-HP-Mini:~/Desktop$ ./img_downloader.sh http://pngimg.com/upload/tree_PNG3498.png -d ff
```

Then the next thing that happens is:

```
Downloading http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Being_a_twin_means_you_always_have_a_pillow_or_blanket_handy.jpg
```

But the problem is the folder on the desktop remains empty even after the download is complete and I have no idea where the file is downloaded.

Comment: use `getopt` for parse arg!

Comment: Which line do you think produced the message, `echo Downloading $url` or `echo Downloading $filename`? Did you make a review of `/tmp/$$.list`? Perhaps post a copy of its contents?